# maven dependency of one project in other?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following dir structure:

```
  parent-proj
          - child proj1
            - pom.xml
          -child proj2
            -pom.xml
          - pom.xml
```

In parent pom.xml i am referring both child projects using module tag.

But my child proj2 refers child proj1 , so when in do mvn install , it fails to compile as proj2 cannot find classes from proj1 ... so what config do i have to put in

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proj2 should have a dependency to proj1, including full groupId, artifactId, version.